# Calculating the roots of a polynomial with parameters

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, nonlinear-system, cubics

I'm dealing with a modelization problem and i've arrived at one point where i need to calculate the roots of a cubic polynomial without specifing their value:
$$
Px^{3}-(Pb+RT)x^{2}+ax-ab=0
$$
I know the value of:

$$a=0.244 \\b=0.026 \\R=0.082$$
But the only information i have about T (temperature, K) and P (pressure, atm) is that:
$$T>0,P>0$$

With the help of python library *sympy* i was able to find the roots analytically
[(result here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBYmW.png), this one is the real root (and the only one i'm interested for my purposes), however my professor suggested to use a numerical method rather than an analytical one.

- My question is: is it possible to calculate the roots of this polynomial **numerically** without specifying their value? And if so, how?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I think your question can be better than the attempt of your question. You already explained the motive of the question, so by doing this, your question will be perfect!

Comment: @RDK I don’t believe there can be an attempt actually here. The problem IMO is just intractable.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Even though it's hard, the 'attempt' is always possible!

Comment: You should either delete your question or post your solution as an answer and accept it (rather than edit into the question).

Comment: @EthanBolker my mistake, i didn't actually find a solution.  The one i edited in was obtained analytically, but my question is if i can reach a similar conclusion numerically, which i wasn't able to do.

Comment: I'm confused. If you have that algebraic solution you can just plug in the values of $P$ and $T$ when you know them. Until you have those values there can't be a "numerical solution". If with the values you prefer a "numerical solution" you can use Newton's method to find the root.

Comment: @EthanBolker If i use Newton's method to find the roots, is there any way i can i do it without specifying a value for T and P?

Comment: That goes into symbolic computation territory. You can do it still with newton, but what you'll get will be not a closed formula, but a black box

Comment: @Exodd Thank you! i'll try to see if i can solve it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $x=V$, you are solving Van der Waals cubic equation of state
$$P=\frac{R T}{V-b}-\frac{a}{V^2}$$ Considering the values given for $a$ and $b$, I am ready to bet that this is for hydrogen.

If you are sure that there is only one real root, you can have much simpler formulae.

Let
$$B=-\frac{R T}{P}-b \qquad \qquad C=\frac a P \qquad \qquad D=- \frac {a b} P$$
Define
$$p=C-\frac{1}{3}B^2 \qquad\qquad \text{and} \qquad\qquad  q=\frac{2 }{27}B^3-\frac{1}{3}BC+D$$

If $\color{red} {p>0}$, then
$$\color{blue} {x=-2\sqrt{\frac{p}{3}}\sinh\left[\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{arsinh}\left(\frac{3q}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{3}{p}}\right)\right]-\frac 13 B}$$

If $\color{red} {p<0}$, then
$$\color{blue} {x=-2\frac{|q|}{q}\sqrt{-\frac{p}{3}}\cosh\left[\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{arcosh}\left(-\frac{3|q|}{2p}\sqrt{\frac{-3}{p}}\right)\right]-\frac 13 B}$$

This formulae are simple and, using them, you do not need any iterative method required by a numerical method.

If you want a numerical approach , Newton method would be the simplest but you need a starting guess $x_0$. Taking into account that for the gas phase, the attraction term $\frac{a}{V^2}$ is very small, ignore it and use
$$x_0=b+\frac{R T}{P}$$

Let me try an example with $T=345$ and $P=123$. The iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.256000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.249242566341334 \\
 2 & 0.248862718778783 \\
 3 & 0.248861544341478 \\
 4 & 0.248861544330268
\end{array}
\right)$$ while working with rational values for $(a,b,R)$ the result is
$$x=\frac 1{375}\Bigg[32+\sqrt{\frac{152686}{41}} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{19459933}{305372}\sqrt{\frac{41}{152686}}\right)\right) \Bigg]$$ which is the exact solution.

If you do not need an extravagant accuracy, using the same $x_0$, the first iterate of Halley method will be
$$x_1=\frac{b P+R T}{P}-\frac{a R T \left(a P+(b P+R T)^2\right)}{a^2 P^2+2 a b P^2 (b P+R T)+(b P+R T)^4}$$ Applied to the example, this gives
$$x_1=\frac{7952127503773}{31951960920500}=0.24887760$$

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much for the clear explanation!

Comment: @dvd. You are welcome ! I worked a lot (as a professional) the area of cubic equations of state. Cheers :-)